# JPA - saving @Version as datatype long

Tags: java, jpa, timestamp

I have a model like this:

```
@Entity
public class Event extends Model {
    @Id
    public long id;

    public String name;

    @Version
    public Timestamp created;
}
```

When running `.save()` on this object, I get the following record:

```
 id | name   |         created
----+--------+-------------------------
  1 | Foobar | 2014-11-04 20:25:40.194
```

As you can see, the `created` field as a SQL Timestamp format. Is it possible to change this to be an actual `BIGINT` or `long` data type? Simply changing `created` to `public long` yields an error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.sql.Timestamp
```

Answer (score 2):

According to JPA 2.0 Specification, chapter 11.1.50 Version Annotation:

> The following types are supported for version properties: int,
>   Integer, short, Short, long, Long, Timestamp.

- if it's possible to drop the existing database schema then it would be enough to replace the entity's `java.sql.Timestamp` field with `java.lang.Long` and recreate database schema again, so the corresponding database column will be replaced with long.
- if it's not possible to drop the existing database schema (i.e. legacy database) then the entity could make an explicit in-place conversion from `java.lang.Long` to `java.sql.Timestamp` with make use of the constructor:

  ```
  Timestamp created = new Timestamp(1397240740194L); //2014-11-04 20:25:40.194
  Long timestamp = created.getTime();
  ```

  I would not recommend using `java.math.BigInteger` for performance reasons unless really necessary (any use-case?).

---

Side note:

> In general, fields or properties that are specified with the Version
>   annotation should not be updated by the application.

In other words, the persistence context takes care of updating version field/column. The application should take care of it only in case of *bulk updates* when the persistence context is omitted and optimistic locking checks are bypassed.

Comment: Dropping the database is not an issue. I've changed the model to use `@Version public Long created`, but that field is now being filled with `1`for each record, instead of something like `System.getCurrentTimeMillis()`. Any ideas?

Comment: The general rule is: every time the entity is updated in the underlying database its version field will increase by one. Try to update the existing entity and the invoke flush/commit.